# The reason for error "The configuration of your org has changed, please reload the page. Missing dependent object: SObject: CustomSettings__Feed"?

Tags: error, gack

I am building a dynamic user interface to traverse fields and relationships and I have faced a strange error on one particular case.

When I have `CustomSettings__c` setting included in a package and also deleted custom setting with the same name in the org, when the following code is executed within the package

```
List<String> toReturn = new List<String>();
    for (SObjectType t: FeedComment.FeedItemId.getDescribe().getReferenceTo()) {
        toReturn.add(t.getDescribe().getName());
    }
    return toReturn;
```

it fails with a strange error

```
The configuration of your org has changed, please reload the page.  Missing dependent object: SObject: CustomSettings__Feed
```

which I cannot catch and log.

This is very strange, since this error doesn't happen when I execute the same code on subscriber org outside of the package.

By reverse engineering and black box testing, I have found out that this error is somehow related to `FeedComment.FeedItemId` field and the presence of duplicate unpackaged custom settings, but I still don't understand why this error happens and what does it mean?

Despite of the suggestion to reload the page, page reload never helps to resolve this.

I am going to open another Salesforce support ticket for this, but if you have any clues of what is going on here, please let me know by answering this question.

Comment: What type of package is this (First Gen Unmanaged, First Gen Managed, Second Gen Unlocked, Second Gen Managed)? Where was this metadata deleted exactly? Have you uploaded/updated to the latest version of your package? Also, do you get an error number? We can do a lot more if we have a Gack ID (at least, for those of us who can communicate with Salesforce engineers).

Comment: 2GMP. The unpackaged duplicate custom setting metadata is deleted

Comment: No gack id for this error, but there is a gack id if you try to erase the subscriber custom setting metadata